# Can't run php file from plesk scheduled tasks

Tags: cron, plesk

I use this command to run php file from plesk scheduled tasks:

> php -q httpdocs/cron.php

but is gives me an error:

> php: command not found

I have linux/centos vps hosting and use exactly the same command on another hosting and it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
/usr/bin/php -q httpdocs/cron.php
```